# Granting restricted permission roles

Tags: 7, users

As well as the three standard roles for a D7 site, I have created a role for a lesser admin / content creator.  This role is essentially an administrator role with some of the juicy bits taken away.

I would like that users assigned this role can manage other users, but I need to restrict it so that they cannot assign or remove the administrator role, or edit an administrator's profile and account.  I can't see a way to do that on the standard installation, is there a module that could help me?

**Edit:**
I have looked into the userprotect module.  While it does prevent a lesser admin from editing an administrator, it does not prevent them from granting the administrator role on themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, [User protect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) should work well. Combine this with [Role Delegation](http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) to restrict what roles they can assign.

Might also be worth keeping an eye on the [Administer Users by Role](http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module, although there is no D7 port yet (in progress [here](http://drupal.org/node/908424)).

Let me know how it turns out as I'm going to be solving this issue on the site I'm working on soon.

Comment: The combination of User Protect and Role Delegation works perfectly. My lesser admins are given the Administer Users permission, but then RD controls which roles they can assign to a user and UP blocks the capability to edit any full admin's account.